# Does the amount of a gas increase with pressure?

Tags: gas-laws, ideal-gas

[image: graph of pv/rt against p]

The graph of $pV/(RT)$ shows that different gases deviate differently from ideal gas behaviour and that the value of $pV/(RT)$ changes as pressure increases.

My question is, if $pV/(RT) = n$ or amount of substance, does this imply that the amount of a gas changes when pressure is applied? This seems a bit confusing to me because I thought that matter cannot be created out of nothing? So where do these extra moles come from/go to?

Comment: To nitpick on the question (I've already edited it to fix these things): (1) The correct term for the "number of moles" of X is the "amount of X", or the ["amount of substance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amount_of_substance). The word "amount" is analogous to "mass", whereas "moles" is a unit that is analogous to "kilograms" (you'd ask *what is the mass of this apple*, not *what is the number of kilograms of this apple*). (2) Please capitalise beginnings of sentences.

Comment: (3) You can use MathJax to typeset mathematical equations; see [FAQ: How can I format math/chemistry expressions on Chemistry Stack Exchange?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/16683) for more information. Your question doesn't need much of it, to be fair.

Comment: @orthocresol "Number of kilograms" is awkward, but I find "amount of X" to be awkward as well.  E.g., suppose you had a container filled with balls, and wanted to ask how many there were.  Would you ask "What is the amount of balls?"  I wouldn't, and don't know anyone who would.  One would instead ask: "What is the quantity of balls?"  Granted, one would not ask "What is the number of dozens of balls?", which points up the problem with saying "What is the number of moles of balls."

Comment: There could be something related to English but I suspect that, like in other languages, the choice of the name "amount of substance" wasn't perfect in this respect. If we stick to definitions all is fine. But in common words, even among scientists, amount can refer to both mass as well as amount of substance. This is not surprising as for there is a linear relationship among the two. To OP: the ideal gases equation is valid for ideal gases only. That is why you call the behaviour "deviation".

Comment: The V in the expression on the diagram is obviously molar volume (volume per mole of gas).  Otherwise, the comparison in the diagram could not be made on a consistent basis.

Comment: @theorist Balls isn't something that we might traditionally measure in moles, which is probably why "amount of balls" sounds very odd. I find "amount of methane" to be rather less awkward — basically, I read it as asking "how much methane is there" but expecting an answer in mols (as opposed to, say, particles). Perhaps I don't find it awkward because I've embraced it, and it just takes a bit more time to win over the chemistry community. But I think it is better wording than "number of moles" (to me, it's unclear whether the latter should take a unit i.e. is the number of moles 2, or 2 mol?).

Answer (score 7):

The whole point of the graph is that $pV/(RT)$ is **no longer equal** to $n$ for a real gas.

$n$ isn't changing (as you point out, this is physically impossible), but the ratio $pV/(RT)$ is changing to some value that is not the same as $n$. Once you're freed from the ideal gas equation, there's no need for $n$ to "follow" the changes in pressure / volume / temperature.

If you prefer, you may wish to recast the "ideal gas equation" as a generalised form that applies to real gases:

$$\frac{pV}{RT} = Zn$$

For a real gas, as $pV/(RT)$ changes, it's not the amount of substance $n$ that changes, but rather the dimensionless quantity $Z$. The latter is called the [compressibility factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility_factor), and in fact is precisely the quantity that is being plotted on the $y$-axis of your graph. Note that this doesn't mean that $Z$ is a *constant*. Its value depends on $p$, $V$, $T$.

Comment: Suggested substitution/extension: «that $pV/(RT)$ is no longer equal to $n$» into «that $pV/(RT)$ is no longer equal to $n$, nor a constant when varying $p$».

Answer (score 1):

Only for ideal gases the equation $pV = nRT$ holds good. Therefore $pV/RT = n$ is valid only for ideal gases. And in the graph, $n$ is constant for ideal gas.

For the real gases $\ce{CH4}$, $\ce{N2}$, $\ce{H2}$, $\ce{CO2}$, while the amount of substance  $n$ is kept constant, the ratio $pV/RT$ is not a constant anymore ($pV/RT \ne n$).

Instead, for real gases

$$\left(p + \frac{an^2}{V^2}\right)(V - nb) = nRT$$

(the Van der Waals equation) is the better description of the observation. So in case of real gases change in $pV/RT$ doesn't indicate change in number of moles.

Comment: van der Waals equation is just one of equations ( even if the most famous) trying to describe  real gas behaviour, more or less successfully. It is not given as a law for real gases. A gas, for which we pretend to behave exactly as the equation describes, is called van der Waals gas.

Comment: See `$CH_4, N_2, H_2, CO_2$` as $CH_4, N_2, H_2, CO_2$ versus `$\ce{CH4, N2, H2, CO2}$` as $\ce{CH4, N2, H2, CO2}$ // For more, see  [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [How can I format math expressions or chem. equations on Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: Please note that using "*number of moles*" in place of proper term amount of substance is as illiterate as to use "*number of grams*" in place of mass. Make sure your notations are correct, too. Element symbols in chemical formulas are upright, $P$ is typically power, and $p$ is pressure, and your fraction $pV/RT$ is ambiguous.

Comment: @Poutnik I realize that due to to recent wave of corrections of the [scientist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Diderik_van_der_Waals)'s name people are afraid to capitalize this Dutch prefix, but you actually should so shall it be the *first word* of a sentence. Also, please don't recommend to block-chain *lists* under a single macro, this backfires in horribly formatted paragraphs with huge gaps. It should never be `$\ce{CH4, N2, H2, CO2}$`, rather `$\ce{CH4},$ $\ce{N2},$ $\ce{H2},$ $\ce{CO2}$`.

Comment: @andselisk To further substantiate your argument: The four page excerpt of the Green Book by Stohner/Quack by 2011 has an entry for pressure as $p$ $(P)$.  But this is *altogether* with the statement that symbols in parentheses (i.e., $P$ for pressure) clearly *is not* the recommended way, but second class.

Comment: @andselisk I am sorry, language-wise I was not sure the initial capitalization applies to the name parts, so it was rather ignorance than omission. // For the formatting, I have not posted it as explicit recommendation. I wanted to merely compare direct application of mhchem via \ce{} on the MJ code as it was. Regarding the splitting, I may want to keep them together in similar ways as the hard(?) spaces keep together words. And, it would be kind of masochism to do so on a phone. Until SE offers MJ/LaTeX editor, one can point out proper ways, but avoid demanding strict-correctness.

Comment: @andselisk it is also true that the symbol *n* for amount of substance doest not help diffuse that sort of literacy.

Answer (score 0):

For an ideal gas, $pV/(RT) = n$ can explain a lot of situations because it contains four variables. If you add gas to an empty Mylar balloon, the volume will increase. If it is still not filled to maximal volume, heating the gas will increase the volume. If you have a full balloon and gently step on it, the pressure will increase; same if you add more gas to it. So it really depends on the specific situation. If you know all four variables and the equation holds, it behaves like an ideal gas, if not, not.